# Writing image header data using jpeglib

Tags: c++, image, jpeg

I want to write the header data of a JPEG image using jpeglib. Unfortunately, I am not exactly sure which header data I really do need. I am sure of:
- quantization table
- Huffman tables
- shared image info (I am not exactly sure which data this contains, somebody wrote about 5 unchangable bytes)

and I know that the usual header size should be 624 bytes.

My code looks like:

```
 jpeg_mem_dest(&cinfo, &buffer, &bufferSize);
 cinfo.image_width = imageWidth;
 cinfo.image_height = imageHeight;
 cinfo.input_components = inputComponents;
 cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;

 jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
 jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo, quality, false);

 jpeg_write_tables(&cinfo);
 jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, false);
 headerSize = bufferSize;
```

How to write only tables is taken from the jpeglib doc section "Abbreviated datastreams and multiple images".
Unfortunately, it writes only 574 bytes and when prepending the written header data to the image data without header it says "JPEG datastream contains no image" when trying to decompress it again.

Analysing an original file which uses a shared header I found the following markers:

markers found are:

```
 FFD8   // Start Of Image
 FFE0   // Application-specific
 FFFE   // Comment
 FFDB   // Define Quantization Table(s)
 FFDB   // Define Quantization Table(s)
 FFC4   // Define Huffman Table(s)

 FFC0   // Start Of Frame (Baseline DCT)

 MIP maps (4 mip maps):

 FFDA
 FFD9
 FFDA
 FFD9
 FFDA
 FFD9
 FFDA
 FFD9
```

Descriptions are taken from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure

From a comment in the original image I do even know the original JPEG compression lib:
Intel(R) JPEG Library, version 1,5,4,36

The point is I want to get the schema behind the format to write exactly the data which is required (apparently some essential image header information is missing otherwise it would at least find a JPEG image I guess).
In the reading process I always prepend the shared header to the image data of one single JPEG image.

Comment: I would look at example.c from the library distribution. Implement the example, see if you get a valid output file, then remove test and repeat. I can verify the example code produces valid jpg files for me.